# Paste selected picture from FSO

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim p As Picture
Dim sPath As String, sFileName As String, s As String

sPath = "C:\Users\Vivek\Downloads\SMCS\"

'Open browser to select a picture
Thisfile = Application.GetOpenFilename

sFileName = Thisfile
s = sPath & sFileName
ActiveSheet.Pictures.insert (s)
```

This code gives me an *error 1004: insert method of picture class failed*.

I want to paste the picture which is copied into the sheets ("CONSOLE") in cell C6.

Comment: You don't need to add the path to the front of Application.GetOpenFilename as the full path is already there. You are basically putting the path in twice.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Protection and Permissions.  This appears to work:

```
Sub GetAPicture()
   Dim s As String, sh As Worksheet
   s = "C:\TestFolder\tempxx.jpg"
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   sh.Pictures.Insert (s)
End Sub
```